# Recommended setup for github jekyll on OS X that supports github flavored markdown

Tags: macos, github, jekyll, redcarpet

I've installed [Jekyll-Bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/), the [redcarpet plugin](https://github.com/nono/Jekyll-plugins), and I've tried updating my Ruby to the latest [RVM stable](https://rvm.io/). I'm running OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.2).

With this setup, if I insert a code block comment with either standard syntax (indent 4 spaces) or github syntax highlighting (```), I end up with no errors from Jekyll and an empty html file (0 bytes). Pushing it to github produces the very helpful error:

> The page build failed with the following error:
>
> page build failed

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you are using Pygments for your highlighting. Although it is strongly pushed by GitHub, I have had much better luck with [**Coderay**](http://svnpenn.github.com/2013/coderay).

Answer (score 0):

The code highlighting in octopress is awesome. I would suggest either trying octopress, or grabbing the relevant plugins and adding them to your jekyll site.

- [code_block](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/plugins/code_block.rb)
- [backtick_code_block](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/plugins/backtick_code_block.rb)
- [pygments_code](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/plugins/pygments_code.rb)
- [raw](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/plugins/raw.rb)

And then you'll need some [css](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/.themes/classic/sass/partials/_syntax.scss).